# Can someone who's gained access to my iCloud account prevent me from receiving text messages?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security

Can someone use my iCloud account to prevent me from receiving messages on my devices from specific people?

I can get calls from a particular person but no text messages for a few days now.

Comment: @wumm Hi! Just want to point out that you removed a critical part of OP's intent in the question in your edit—be careful that you're not drastically modifying the point of a question when you edit; thanks

Comment: @grgarside Indeed, I've completely changed the meaning of the first sentence. Thank you for watching out.

Answer (score 1):

No.

iCloud has nothing to do with Text Messages (SMS).

iMessages are sent to all your devices, so even if someone was using your iCloud credentials, you would still receive the iMessages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your version of iOS but **it is possible** that the **iCloud-synced list of blocked phone numbers** could mean that they can block people in your contacts so you won't receive any messages, including SMS.

Other than that one aspect, your carrier SMS will flow whether or not your iCloud account is secure or compromised.

Comment: Good point, but that will also prevent THEM from getting them. It's all or nothing.